# 'React/RCTEventDispatcherProtocol.h' file not found in M1 chip React native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

i am facing this issue when i try to build on ios simulator.
these are my react versions
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "~0.63.4",
Xcode: 13.1
node: 12.22.7

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.